# Deletar Todas SharedPreferences de Aplicação Android

Tags: android

Estou no meio de um desenvovimento de uma aplicação em ANDROID, que contém muitas Activity e para cada Activity tem alguns checkBox e estou usando SharedPreferences para guardar o  que estava selecionado caso o usuário queira voltar na tela.
Mas preciso deletar todas as SharedPreferences ao iniciar a aplicação. Como que posso fazer isso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = getSharedPreferences(arquivo, 0).edit();
prefsEditor.clear();
prefsEditor.commit();
```

Isso removerá todos os valores guardados.

Comment: No  getSharedPreferences(), esta me obrigando a passar todas as String. Teria algum modo, sendo que todas as SharedPreferences estão com o mesmo nome.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz desta forma:

```
public void deletarSharedPreferences()
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

On kotlin:

```
val security: SharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(String, Int)
security.edit().clear().apply()
```

`String` is the name of the SharedPreferences file and `int` is the Context passed.

Example:

```
class SecurityPreferences(context: Context) {

    private val security: SharedPreferences =
        context.getSharedPreferences("Explanation", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    fun clearCache(){
        security.edit().clear().apply()
    }
}
```